# Web page cannot zoom in/out

Tags: html, mobile, web

I have added below meta tag to my web page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">
```

But this only successful change the default zoom level on mobile . user-scalable=yes is no effect ...

Any idea ??

Modification :

Tested on android 4.4 Nexus 4 , chrome 36.0

Tap to zoom is working , but pinch to zoom is not work .....

Comment: What mobile device/OS?

Comment: Andorid , chrome 36.0

Answer (score 0):

you need to create **CSS** file and add **media** tag in your stylesheet after that according to your mobile size the web page is display setting change automatically ... See this

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/